# Is there a standard terminology for the preorder induced by a monotone map?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, monotone-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. Then the [*kernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory)) of $f$ is the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$.
I would like to know whether there is an accepted terminology in the ordered case, although I would be happy to use *kernel* also in this case.

More precisely, let $(X, \leqslant)$ and $(Y, \leqslant)$ be (pre)ordered sets and let $f:X \to Y$ be a monotone map. Is there a standard name for the preorder $\preccurlyeq$ on $X$ defined by $x \preccurlyeq y$ if and only if $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$?